# Pug pass variable to 'include:marked'

Tags: pug

I'm trying to pass a variable from express to my Jade view like so:

**From my server.js:**

```
app.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { md: 'index' });
});
```

**To my .pug:**

```
html
  body
    block content
      include:marked ../md/#{md}.md
```

I just keep on getting an error about 'no file #{md}'

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2304). As far I can tell from that issue report, this functionality is simply not supported at the moment by the Pug system. It is, however, "on the roadmap for 3.0.0".

**Edit:**
See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579461/jade-doesnt-let-me-use-include-variable-in-a-mixin), as well. It also relates to the same issue of variables in includes.

Comment: You could have a look at the workaround presented in the first answer of the question I linked (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12133319). It proposes prerendering the content you want to include and then passing the rendered html to the template as context variable (not the cleanest way, but should work).

Comment: Yea, that work around worked, kinda sucks though, hopefully pug 3 comes soon.