# Variable in a Jade include cause

Tags: node.js, templates, variables, include, pug

I want to include a HTML file in a jade template. The path and name of the file is a variable/parameter which is sent by the server after the user request.

Snippet of index.js

```
app.get('/material/*', function(req, res){
  var lpath =  "../static/show/" + req.name;  // req.name looks like newSite.html
  res.render("newView.jade", {lpath: lpath});
});
```

code of newView.jade

```
include !{lpath}
```

but then the browser shows

```
Error: E:\Git\GitHub\chat-example\views\lecture.jade:1
  > 1| include !{lpath} 
    2| 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\newSite\views\!{lpath}.jade'
 at Error (native)
 at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
```

I tested whether *lpath* is correct and it is. If I add the lpath i that way

```
include ../static/show/newSite.html
```

everything is fine. I've also tried the pipe (see [Use a variable in a Jade include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132978/use-a-variable-in-a-jade-include))

```
|!{lpath}
```

Thanks for any ideas and hints.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `lpath` to `render()` will not work. I also had the same problem what you will need to do is compile the files manually and then concatinate then something like

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

app.get('/material/*', function(req, res){
  var htmlPart = ejs.compile(
      fs.readFileSync(path.join("../static/show/",req.name), 'utf8')); 
  var ejsPart = ejs.compile(
      fs.readFileSync(path.join("../relative_path_to_newView.jade","req.name"), 'utf8'));
  var resBody = htmlPart + ejsPart;
  res.send(resBody);
    });
```

you may use asynchronous functions also
hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It works fine now. But there is a small error in your code. See comments in your snippet.