# Render passed argument in node.js as text

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am using node.js, express with jade/pug.

As an example I have the following in an index.js file.

```
 res.render('index', { x: 'home' });
```

As a test to make sure I am passing the value correctly I am using the following to display the value 'home' on index.pug.

```
 #{x}
```

This renders the value as the tag home.

```
 <home></home> instead of the word home
```

How do I get the word home instead of a tag?
How would I get the value into

```
 include ../components/#{x}.pug
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: just specify a tag before it like: `h1 #{x}` or `h1= x`

Comment: sorry andrew.butkus I edited the question.

Comment: Are you using jade or ejs ?

Comment: timolawl that works.  However what I am ultimately trying to do is use the value that is passed to have a specific view loaded based on app routing.  So I would like to have an  include ../components/#{x}.pug and get home in place of the #{x}

Comment: you should change the question to describe that, then. @SofieneDJEBALI, that's jade

Comment: Sofiene: Using Jade or the current name pug.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12133319/5812121