# Including a pug filter which name is in a variable

Tags: node.js, pug

In the Pug [Language reference](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html) there is an easy example on how to use the markdown filter on a .md file and include it.

```
include:markdown-it myfile.md
```

However, I can't get to work reading from a file which name is in a variable. I expected this syntax to work:

```
include:markdown-it ${article}
```

Being `var article = 'myfile.md'`. But the code crash saying it can't find file '${article}' in my views folder.

What is the correct way of doing it? Or is it just imposible?

Regards.

**EDIT**: As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132978/use-a-variable-in-a-jade-include), it's not possible to do what I want. The solution I found was rendering the markdown file first,

```
function loadmd(md) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var markdown = require('markdown-it')();
    var mdfile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/mds/' + md + '.md');
    return markdown.render(mdfile.toString());
}
```

and then pass it to the pug renderer as a variable:

```
res.render('art', {md: loadmd(req.params.article)}, function renderDone(err, html) { ... }
```

Template:

```
doctype html
html(lang=es)
head
    include htmlhead
    title !{pagetitle}
body
    include pageheader
    include pagemenu
    section
        article !{md}
    footer
        include pagefooter
```

Comment: Pug interpolation uses a hash instead `#{...}`.

Comment: @sean Isn't working. Same error again, can't find '#{article}' file in views folder.

Comment: Actually I don't think Pug allows for variables in include statements sadly.

Comment: Lots of discussion about it here though: https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1990

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a variable in a Jade include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132978/use-a-variable-in-a-jade-include)