# Connecting include PUG files

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I can't connect another file via "include ./pages/#{page}. pug". Can you tell me how to make it connect?

```
let renderPage = (res, page) => {
    res.render ('html', {data: {page: 'index'}})
}

html
    head
        title=title
        style
        include ./css/styles.css
    body
        case data.page 
            when 'index'
                include ./pages/#{page}.pug

            default
                p Ошибка 404. Страница не найдена
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a variable in a Jade include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132978/use-a-variable-in-a-jade-include)

Comment: Dynamic include pathes are not possible.